# vue js state based logic for multiple ul li elements

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html-lists

I have ul with static ammount of li's (menu elements), rendered on server side. I need to implement some state-based logic on every li (active li recoloring, opening a nested subpoints). How do I describe it on vue, except creating a new vue object for every li? Thanks a lot!
P.S. sry, I'm new at vue js, need to catch a concept in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    array: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    myObject: {
      A: 'a',
      B: 'b',
      C: 'c'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, indice) in array">{{item}} - {{indice}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, cle, indice) in myObject">{{cle}} : {{item}} - {{indice}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```